# creating this famous basic nyquist theory photo

Tags: matlab, fft, sampling, dft, nyquist

Hello i ha built this code
which create a  only one replica of the data,
how can i create the whole photo shown bellow of many cycles as shown bellow?
i read in the internet that zero padding could create it,but its not wotking.
How could it be done?
Thanks.

```
f1=10;
f2=20;
f3=70;
% twice the sampling rate
Fs=2.05*70; % sampling frequency is a bit above 2 times to get all the peaks.
Ts=1/Fs;
Tn=0:Ts:1;
fft_L=length(Tn);
y4_samples=10*sin(2*pi*f1*Tn)+10*sin(2*pi*f2*Tn)+10*sin(2*pi*f3*Tn);
%stem(Tn_new,y4_samples);
ff=fft(y4_samples);
ff1 = abs(ff/fft_L);
fft2 = ff1(1:floor(fft_L/2)+1);
fft2(2:end) = 2*fft2(2:end);
f = Fs*(0:fft_L/2)/fft_L;
plot(f, fft2)
```

[image: nyquist sampling]

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/66031/38419

Answer (score 0):

Try upsample command in MATLAB. Upsampling (interleaving by zeros) will create replicas of fourier transform. You can then re-label your x-axis appropriately. Example of fft of y4_samples upsampled by 4 below.

[image]

Adding code :

```
f1=10;
f2=20;
f3=70; 
% twice the sampling rate 
Fs=2.05*70; % sampling frequency is a bit above 2 times to get all the peaks. 
Ts=1/Fs;
Tn=0:Ts:1;
fft_L=length(Tn);
y4_samples=10*sin(2*pi*f1*Tn)+10*sin(2*pi*f2*Tn)+10*sin(2*pi*f3*Tn);
y5=upsample(y4_samples,4);
fft_L=fft_L*4; %update fft_L
%stem(Tn_new,y4_samples);
ff=fft(y5);
ff1 = abs(ff/fft_L);
f = Fs*(-fft_L/2:fft_L/2-1)/fft_L;
plot(f, ff1)
```

Comment: could you please post the code of the upsample command you used to create these replicas?
Thanks

Comment: $y = upsample(x,4)$ is what I used here to create 4 replicas.

Comment: Hello i Have tried to use the upsample command its not working
as shown in the code bellow.
Where did i go wrong?

f1=10;

f2=20;

f3=70;
% twice the sampling rate
Fs=2.05*70; % sampling frequency is a bit above 2 times to get all the peaks.
Ts=1/Fs;
Tn=0:Ts:1;
fft_L=length(Tn);
y4_samples=10*sin(2*pi*f1*Tn)+10*sin(2*pi*f2*Tn)+10*sin(2*pi*f3*Tn);
y5=upsample(y4_samples,4);
%stem(Tn_new,y4_samples);
ff=fft(y5);

ff1 = abs(ff/fft_L);

fft2 = ff1(1:floor(fft_L/2)+1);

fft2(2:end) = 2*fft2(2:end);

f = Fs*(0:fft_L/2)/fft_L;
plot(f, fft2)

Comment: There is a mistake in your code. When you did upsample by 4, your frequency axis length became 4 times. But you did not account for this. I will add the corrected code in my answer. I added line 11.

Comment: You are plotting only positive frequencies. Is that enough? You do not want to show negative frequencies?

Comment: yes , negative frequencies will be great

Comment: Updated the code

Comment: Thank you very much.